# Comparing dates in Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

The following is meant to compare a Date of Birth and confirm the individual is 10 years old or greater. It appears to work, however I want some advice to improve or ensure my logic is correct for my date comparison within Selenium IDE. Do I need to use Date.parse() to turn these to milliseconds as per this [advice](http://seleniumluckystrike.blogspot.com.au/2013/02/comparing-some-dates.html) or will these proper date formats be sufficient to compare them accurately?

```
<tr>
<td>storeEval</td>
<td>new Date(&quot;${DateOfBirthYear}&quot;,&quot;${DateOfBirthMonth}&quot;-1,&quot;${DateOfBirthDay}&quot;);</td>
<td>DateOfBirthAsDate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>storeEval</td>
<td>new Date();</td>
<td>today</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>storeEval</td>
<td>(Date.prototype.addMonth = function(month) { var dat = new Date(this.valueOf()); dat.setMonth(dat.getMonth() + month); return dat; }); var dat = storedVars['today'];dat.addMonth(-120)</td>
<td>DateOfBirthEleven</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>storeEval</td>
<td>(storedVars['DateOfBirthEleven'] &lt; storedVars['DateOfBirthAsDate'] ) ? true : false</td>
<td>AgeOK</td>
</tr>
```

Advice and suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks fine. I wouldn't change it if it works - comparing milliseconds won't make any difference when you are comparing days.

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like this:

```
var a = new Date('03/21/1980');
var b = new Date('03/21/1989');
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
var yearDiff = b.getYear() - a.getYear();
if( yearDiff >= 10) {
  console.log("over 10!");
}
else if (yearDiff >= 9) {
 //compare milliseconds for 1 year
 console.log("over 9!"); 
}
```

Just because a "year" is different with leaps, etc... but if their over 10 clearly you can skip semantics...

Sorry, didn't have time to put into seleniumese

Comment: var yearDiff = b.getYear() - a.getYear() ..that just checks the year.. what if they turn 10 during the year?

Comment: Isn't that what my "else" statement handles?

Comment: var b = new Date('03/20/1990'); and var b = new Date('03/22/1990'); should give <10 and >=10 respectively. Yours give >=10 for both.